# load a content dynamically without reloading

Tags: jquery, html

I want to load the content without reloading the whole page.

What is wrong with this code?

Also, how to make transitions between these pages?

If I click on services from the home page I wish to create a fade in/out effect.

I'm completely new to jQuery.

Here is my code

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Untitled Document</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->
     <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function updateContainer( url ){
         dynamicCon = '#content';    
         ObjTag = $( dynamicCon );
         ObjTag.load( url );
       }
       $( document ).ready( function() {
         $( 'a[rel="dynamicLoad"]' ).bind( "click", function( event ) {
           url = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
           alert(url);
           updateContainer( url );
           event.preventDefault();
           event.stopPropagation();
         });
       });
     </script>
     </head>
```

This is the body content :

[image]

stackoverflow was parsing it.

Comment: is $ already declared as jQuery`?

Comment: you mean i added jquery.js file ? if yes, then yea i have added it

Comment: @Mik I only see the jQuery CDN reference, so `$(...)` does map to `jQuery(..)` in this instance.

Comment: i have tried downloading the file and putting it in the folder itself. same problem :/ this is the link to it btw `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: you aren't telling us much about what happens when you run the code. what exactly have you tried debugging wise? does the alert contain the correct url? are there any js errors in the javascript console after you click one of these links? does loading the urls by typing them in to you browser work? what is the length of $( 'a[rel="dynamicLoad"]' ), meaning are we sure it is finding the elements we think it is finding? i noticed you are using `dynamicCon` and `ObjTag` as global variables instead of declaring them as local variables with `var`. is this messing up anything in jQuery?

Comment: Sir i have modified the whole code but it seems that the `.load() ` function is not working. This is the link to my files. kindly try this out and tell me whats wrong with it. https://www.yousendit.com/download/WUJZTkZrQXBZY1NFTmNUQw

Comment: Sir the js has no issues, the compiler says its fine. but it's not able to load the file am putting in the `.load ('file path')`.

Comment: look at my code and tell me what is wrong with it is not generally how this works. no one is going to download your files. you should have a specific programming question. what makes you think load isn't working? I can assure you that it does indeed work. your problem lies elsewhere. can you answer all of the questions in my above comment?

Comment: you can see the basics of you above code working perfectly fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/8SQP9/

Comment: sir, i have been trying this for so so long. its not working. now am trying to simply load an html file content in place of an already existing text, even that is not working. Am using this `$('#content').load('home.html');`

Comment: here content is that div id of the text which i want to replace and home.html is the page i want to display in place of the text covered by div id=content.
yes, i have checked the directory status. even for simplicity i have put all files in one folder. :/

Comment: oh god its working in FIREFOX

Answer (score 0):

The `.load()` function doesn't work in chrome .. Its working fine in firefox/ie.